# ChromeDriver keeps lauching several times

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

when i lauch the below test, chrome keeps lauching several times which leads to test fail. I have been debugging for the past 2 days and can't find the issue. could you please point me to where i am making mistakes, any help will be much appreciated !

WebDriver ChromeDrive Class

```
public class LauchDriver {

    
    public WebDriver LauDriver(){
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup() ;
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }
   

}
```

The Object class

```
    public class ContactpageObjects {
    
        public ContactpageObjects( ){
            LauchDriver laudriver = new LauchDriver();     
            PageFactory.initElements(laudriver.LauDriver(), this);
        }
    
        @FindBy(css = ".hero")
        List<WebElement> header1 ;
    
        @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@class = 'search__input'][@data-highlight = 'true']")
        WebElement searchField;
    
        @FindBy(xpath = ".//button[@class = 'search__submit']")
        WebElement submit;
    
    
        public List<WebElement> getHeader(){
            return header1;
        }
    
        public WebElement getSearchField(){
            return searchField;
        }
    public WebElement getSubmit(){
        return submit;
    }

    
}
```

Test class

```
public class ContactPageTest 
{

    public ContactpageObjects getObjects(){
        ContactpageObjects obj = new ContactpageObjects();
        return obj;
    }
 
    @Test
    public void enterSearchText(){
        LauchDriver lauch = new LauchDriver();
        lauch.LauDriver().get("https://www.mywebsite.uk/speed");
        for(WebElement a:getObjects().getHeader()){
            
            String text = a.findElement(By.cssSelector(".hero__title")).getText();
            assertEquals("Contact", text);
            System.out.println(text);
    
            }
         ContactpageObjects obj = new ContactpageObjects();

        obj.getSearchField().sendKeys("closing");
        getObjects().getSubmit().click(); 
       
    }

     @Test
    public void contactHeader()
    {
        
        for(WebElement a:getObjects().getHeader()){
            
        String text = a.findElement(By.cssSelector(".hero__title")).getText();
        assertEquals("Contact", text);
        System.out.println(text);

        }
        
    }


   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not passing driver to the page object class. For below class parameter should be driver and that should be passed from test case. Create Launch Driver object in Before Method and pass driver to the Page Objects.

```
public ContactpageObjects(WebDriver driver){ 
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```